# How to put a background color behind a form?

Tags: html, css

I am able to get the desired style with my text elements but not with my form. I was previously trying to achieve this in a mockup practice website I was working on and decided to just attempt it on a clean slate. As you can see I am able to get the background color on the screen but now it stacks. I started looking at the structure of my HTML and there is nothing I can think of that would produce the outcome I am getting. The red opposed to the form itself is in a column though and I have flex-direction column on on my 'form' in my css so maybe it is the structure and I am missing something? Help would be much appreciated & thank you in advance!

[What my code is producing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8PkNj.jpg)

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Raleway:wght@300;400;500&display=swap');

/* page style */

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#contact-page {
  font-family: 'Raleway';
  background: #464B59;
}

/* contact grid (container) */

.contact-grid {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  height: 100vh;
  
}

/* contact-info */

.contact-info {
  background: white;
  padding: 80px;
  max-width: 500px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 200;
}

.contact-info h2 {
  font-size: 40px;
}

/* form */

.form {
  width: 400px;
  height: 500px;
  border: green 2px solid;
  background: red;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}

form {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <title>contact</title>
</head>
<body id="contact-page">

  <div class="contact-grid">
  
    <div class="contact-info">
      <h2>get in touch</h2>
      <hr>
      <p>The best way to reach me directly is via Linkden.</p>
      <p>If you are looking inquire proffesionally please fill out the contact form and I will get back to you as soon as I can.</p>
      <p>Thank you & have a wonderful day</p>
    </div>

    <div class="form">
      <form action="https://formsubmit.co/your@email.com" method="POST">
        <input type="text" name="name" required placeholder="name">
        <input type="email" name="email" required placeholder="email">
        <textarea name="message" id="" cols="30" rows="10" placeholder="message"></textarea>
        <button type="submit">Send</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Apply the "background: red; " in the (form) selector not in the class (.form) selector. and if this helped delete the question, please.

Comment: .form {
  width: 400px;
  height: 500px;
  border: green 2px solid;
  height: max-content;
  width: max-content;
}

form {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color:red;

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
 @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Raleway:wght@300;400;500&display=swap');

/* page style */

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#contact-page {
  font-family: 'Raleway';
  background: #464B59;
}

/* contact grid (container) */

.contact-grid {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  height: 100vh;
  
}

/* contact-info */

.contact-info {
  background: white;
  padding: 80px;
  max-width: 500px;
  text-align: center;
}

.contact-info h2 {
  font-size: 40px;
}

/* form */

.form {
  width: 600px;
  padding:20px;
  border: green 2px solid;
  background: red;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}

form {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
form input{
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
form textarea{
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
form button{
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <title>contact</title>
</head>
<body id="contact-page">

  <div class="contact-grid">
  
    <div class="contact-info">
      <h2>get in touch</h2>
      <hr>
      <p>The best way to reach me directly is via Linkden.</p>
      <p>If you are looking inquire proffesionally please fill out the contact form and I will get back to you as soon as I can.</p>
      <p>Thank you & have a wonderful day</p>
    </div>

    <div class="form">
      <form action="https://formsubmit.co/your@email.com" method="POST">
        <input type="text" name="name" required placeholder="name">
        <input type="email" name="email" required placeholder="email">
        <textarea name="message" id="" cols="30" rows="10" placeholder="message"></textarea>
        <button type="submit">Send</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thank you Suresh. I can't upvote this because my reputation is low but this worked. thank you.

Comment: No worry brother !